# Replace all digit and asterisk characters except at start of string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to replace all characters in a string except for any that are at the start of a string (or part of a word).

For example, lines of text read from a CSV file:

```
MSFT *<E07004QY6W>
WOOLWORTHS W1157
GOOGLE*ADWS7924436927
COLES 0829
ROBLOX.COM 888-858-25
7-ELEVEN 2179
COLES EXPRESS 1896
```

result should be:

```
MSFT
WOOLWORTHS
GOOGLE
COLES
ROBLOX.COM
7-ELEVEN
COLES EXPRESS
```

Can JavaScript replace() regular expression achieve this?

Tried so far:

- '/\d+/g' - but it removes ALL digits and nothing else
- '/(*|\d+$)/' - but this doesn't quite work on some, results in "ROBLOX.COM 888-858-"

Comment: Are all the lines part of the same string? Meaning are they seperated by `\n`?

Comment: elaborate your question: is it always multiline string separated by newline?

Comment: Values are read from a CSV file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `/(\s+(\S+\d+\S+)|\*\S+)/g`

**Demo**

```js
function replaceRegex( input )
{
  return input.replace( /(\s+(\S+\d+\S+)|\*\S+)/g, "" );
}

console.log( replaceRegex( "MSFT *<E07004QY6W>" ) );
console.log( replaceRegex( "WOOLWORTHS W1157" ) ); //output is WOOLWORTHS W1157 but it matches your rules 
console.log( replaceRegex( "GOOGLE*ADWS7924436927" ) );
console.log( replaceRegex( "COLES 0829" ) );
console.log( replaceRegex( "7-ELEVEN 2179" ) );
console.log( replaceRegex( "COLES EXPRESS 1896" ) );
```

Comment: Very close. just doesn't work properly on "ROBLOX.COM-858-25", would like to trim down to "ROBLOX.COM" .

Comment: this, unfortunately, won't replace `W1157` in the 2nd line, while it should

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest As per the rules given by OP *replace-all-digit-and-asterisk-characters-except-at-start-of-string*, it matces.

Comment: @gurvinder372, as per the OP's *result should be:* section -  `W1157` is replaced

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split(/\ |\*/)[0]` this will split on either a space or * and return you the first work

```js
var tests = ["MSFT *<E07004QY6W>",
  "WOOLWORTHS W1157",
  "GOOGLE*ADWS7924436927",
  "COLES 0829",
  "ROBLOX.COM 888-858-25",
  "7-ELEVEN 2179",
  "COLES EXPRESS 1896"
];

tests = tests.map(v => {
  return v.split(/(\s+\w+\d+|\*\S+)/)[0]
})

console.log(tests)
```

Comment: Interesting idea, however where two-words exist, like "COLES EXPRESS 1896" it's reducing down to "COLES" instead of "COLES EXPRESS"

Comment: Update, should work now, might be better to choose gurvinder372's answer tho :)